# Python stdin readline over 4096 bytes in linux x64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I have an input line that is longer than 4096 bytes coming into stdin in Python. The code simply says:

```
while True:
    task_json = sys.stdin.readline()
    task_json = json.loads(task_json.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8- sig', 'surrogateescape'))
```

which is truncating line at 4096 bytes. Anyone know a solution?
I use python3.6 on ubuntu 16.04 x64. I tried use -u flag - not work. Size of my raw is 9k byte. I can not split this line for \n and modify, i need only stdin from console.
May be i can configure console mode, switch to non canon mode?

Comment: Could not reproduce on Python 3.7 & Bash. The script takes 9k byte input as it should.

Comment: How are you inputting the data? With redirection or pasted into the terminal? It may be some limitation of the terminal if the latter.

Comment: In python3.7 you could try to reconfigure `stdin` to change newline handling to see if the issue is with universal newlines...

Answer (score 1):

Canonical mode of TTY needs to be disabled.

```
def getline(prompt=""):
  fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
  old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
  new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
  new[3] = new[3] & ~termios.ICANON
  try:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)
    line = input(prompt)
  finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
  return line
```